# DocumentDB Data Migration Tool - transformDocument procedure with partitions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to convert data from SQL Server to DocumentDb.  I need to create embedded arrays in the DocumentDb document.

I am using the DocumentDb Data Migration Tool and it describes using the transformDocument for a bulk insert stored proc...unfortunately we are using partitioned collections and they do not support bulk insert.

Am I missing something or is this not currently supported?

Answer (score 0):

The migration tool only supports sequential data import to a partitioned collection. Please follow sample below to bulk-import data efficiently into a partition collection.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/documentdb-benchmark